# WPF SpinEdit only allow to enter or input value between min and max value

Tags: wpf, window

I am using SpinEdit and only want user to enter or input value between min and max value. I have added MinValue and MaxValue property and EditValueChanging event only allow value between Min and Max value. But EditValueChanging event only fire one time only.

Example, I have entered 12 in SpinEdit and event only fire when I entered 1. May I know how to only allow value between Min and Max value only.

```
private void OnEditValueChanging(object sender, EditValueChangingEventArgs e)
    {
        decimal val = Convert.ToDecimal(e.NewValue);
        if (val > SpinEdit.MaxValue || val < SpinEdit.MinValue)
        {
            e.IsCancel = true;
            SpinEdit.EditValue = "";
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is SpinEdit a DevExpress control?

Comment: Yes, It is DevExpress Control for wpf

Comment: I have had the same problem with various DevExpress controls. I HATE DevExpress. They make the easiest tasks so difficult. Do you have a mask set on the SpinEdit?

Answer (score 0):

To prevent a user from entering values that don't fall within a range specified with MaxValue and MinValue, set the SpinEdit.AllowRoundOutOfRangeValue property to "True".